# Can you solve this integral$?$: $\int\frac{4x\ln(x)}{3x^2+2x+1}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, complex-analysis, special-functions

Find the value of the following integral $$\int\frac{4x\ln(x)}{3x^2+2x+1}dx$$ I have no idea how to solve this integral. I tried all the ways of doing it(parts, substitution and many more) but I got stuck every time at the beginning. Please help me to solve this. By the way, calculations involving complex numbers, polylogarithms and special integrals are allowed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: There are no bounds on the integral.
EDIT: I'm asking for the anti derivative.

Comment: The integral is divergent, no?

Comment: Are there meant to be bounds on the integral?

Comment: @Sal no there are no bounds

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken, what you’re actually asking for is the *antiderivative*, right?

Comment: @Aphelli I guess so.

Comment: @Aphelli yes sir

Comment: Unlike YouTube videos, on this site you don't need to use words like "crazy" in the title. They only decrease the quality of your post - see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) point 2, [choose a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).

Comment: You mentioned “I tried all ways of doing it”, but can you write one or two of them out please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've just gotta brute force it. Since
$$
3x^2 +2x+1 = 3(x- \alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})
$$
where $\alpha = -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}i$ is one of the roots of the polynomial, you can apply partial fractions to get
$$
\frac{x}{(x-\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - \overline{\alpha}} \frac{1}{x-\alpha}+\frac{\overline{\alpha}}{ \overline{\alpha}-\alpha} \frac{1}{x-\overline{\alpha}}
$$
Then the problem reduces to evaluating $\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x-a}\mathrm{d}x$. For this last family of antiderivatives frist [recall](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.12) that
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(t) = -\int\frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}\, \mathrm{d}t 
$$
So we get
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\ln(x)}{x-a}\, \mathrm{d}x& = \frac{1}{a}\int \frac{\ln(x)}{\frac{x}{a}-1}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
& \overset{u =x/a}{=} \int \frac{\ln(u) + \ln(a)}{u-1}\, \mathrm{d}u \\
& \overset{s = 1-u}{=} \ln(a) \int \frac{1}{u-1}\, \mathrm{d}u + \int \frac{\ln(1-s)}{s}\, \mathrm{d}s \\
& = \ln(a) \ln(u-1)  - \operatorname{Li}_2(s)\\
& = \ln(a)\ln\left(\frac{x}{a}-1\right) -\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1- \frac{x}{a}\right)
\end{align}
And combining everything we get
\begin{align}
\int \frac{4x\ln(x)}{3x^2 +2x+1}\, \mathrm{d}x &= \frac{4}{3}\int\frac{x\ln(x)}{(x-\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})}\, \mathrm{d}x\\
& = \frac{4}{3} \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - \overline{\alpha}} \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x-\alpha} \, \mathrm{d}x +\frac{4}{3} \frac{\overline{\alpha}}{ \overline{\alpha}-\alpha} \int \frac{\ln(x)}{x-\overline{\alpha}} \, \mathrm{d}x\\
& = \frac{4}{3} \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - \overline{\alpha}} \left[ \ln(\alpha)\ln\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}-1\right) -\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1- \frac{x}{\alpha}\right)\right]+\frac{4}{3} \frac{\overline{\alpha}}{ \overline{\alpha}-\alpha}\left[\ln(\overline{\alpha})\ln\left(\frac{x}{\overline{\alpha}}-1\right) -\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1- \frac{x}{\overline{\alpha}}\right) \right]
\end{align}
where $\alpha =  -\frac{1}{3} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}i$ and $\overline{\alpha} =  -\frac{1}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}i$.

Comment: So we conclude this integral is not elementary, since $\operatorname{Li}_2$ is not elementary.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int\frac{4x\ln x}{3x^{2}+2x+1} = \ln x\int\frac{4x}{3x^{2}+2x+1}dx - \int\frac{1}{x}\int\frac{4x}{3x^{2}+2x+1}dxdx. $$

This is by integration by parts.

Recall $$ \int \frac{dx}{x^{2}+1} = \arctan(x) + C $$

so you can complete the square of the denominator:
$$ 3x^{2} + 2x + 1 = (\sqrt{3}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2} + \frac{2}{3}. $$
Therefore
$$ \int\frac{1}{3x^{2}+2x+1}dx = \int\frac{dx}{(\sqrt{3}x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2} + \frac{2}{3}} = \int\frac{dx}{3(x+\frac{1}{3})^{2} + \frac{2}{3}} = (u = x - \frac{1}{3}) = \int\frac{du}{3u^{2}+\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{du}{u^{2}+\frac{2}{9}} = \frac{3}{2}\int\frac{du}{\frac{9}{2}u^{2}+1}  = (z = \sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}u) =\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}\int\frac{dz}{z^{2}+1} = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}\arctan(z)+ C = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}(x-\frac{1}{3}))+ C. $$

Now you can use this knowledge for the first integral.
$$\int\frac{x}{3x^{2}+2x+1}dx = x\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}(x-\frac{1}{3})) - \int\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2}{9}}\arctan(\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}}(x-\frac{1}{3}))dx.$$

It is well known that $$ \int \arctan(x)dx = x\arctan(x) - \frac{1}{2}\ln|1+x^{2}| + C. $$

By similar tricks to those I used to derive the integral you may solve the second one. Do not forget to multiply both results by $4$ in the end.

Comment: I believe the integration by parts part is wrong. The last integral should be 
$$
\int \left(\frac{1}{x} \int \frac{4x}{3x^2 +2x+1}\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}x
$$
But that inner integral evaluates to logarithms and arctangents of polynomials, which seems even more complicated to me.

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry.

Comment: You can use arctangents and logarithms of polynomias.....I specified the use of special integrals and polylogarithms